# Changing the lines of the arrowhead in circuitikz

Tags: color, arrows, circuitikz

First of all, this is a crosspost from the german website [golatex.de](https://golatex.de/pfeilespitze-in-circuitikz-anpassen-t21785.html).
I am hoping another set of eyes on it might help find a solution.

If I draw two voltage sources with circuitikz and the second voltage source is dotted (or dashed), the arrowhead is not adjusted. It remains normal and the dotted (or dashed) lines are just "drawn over".

My minimal working example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
   (8,2) to [american voltage source, v_<=$\omega_RL_qi_q$] (8,4);

\draw[lightgray,dotted] %or dashed
  (8,0) to [american voltage source, v_<=$\omega_R\psi$,color=lightgray] (8,2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

In the picture it can be seen that everything of the second voltage source can be colored but the arrowhead remains normal and the dotted (or dashed) lines are just "drawn over" as mentioned above.

[image]

What do I have to do to get the arrowhead also dotted (or dashed)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I know. The problem is that arrows in `circuitikz` are not real arrows, but they are built manually with the `currarrow` shape. I am not sure why, but probably because `circuitikz` predates `arrows.meta` and... whatever. I plan to change it, but it is a big change, and difficult to do in a backward compatible way.

If you change, in the definition of `currarrow` (file `pgfcircshapes.tex`, at line 308 in current git version) the command

```
\pgfusepath{draw,fill}
```

into

```
\pgfusepath{fill}
```

the result is a bit better (see below), but I am not sure if it can have other nasty effects around. If you want, you can open an [issue on github](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues) so that I can track it...

[image]

Otherwise, you can remove the `fill`, but now you have a quite bad effect on the rest of the circuit:

[image]

(yes, this is the dotted version of the arrow outline. Quite bad, but the points are random, and not lined up with the corners. I really do not know how to make a dotted or dashed outline of an arrow work. `densely dotted` gives:

[image]

but still...)

Notice that the standard arrows do not change with linestyle, and although you can make them unfilled, there is no provision (chapter  16.3 of the 3.0.1 TikZ manual) to make them something not solid:

```
\draw[-{Triangle[fill=none, ]}, densely dotted] (9,0) -- (10,0);
```

[image]

#### Stop gap solution...

You can redefine the shape and add a bit of configurability like that:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}

\makeatletter

%% Current arrow
\def\arrowfilldraw{\pgfusepath{draw,fill}}
\def\arrowfillonly{\pgfusepath{fill}}
\let\arrowuse=\arrowfilldraw
\tikzset{ctikzarrdraw/.is choice}
\tikzset{ctikzarrdraw/true/.code={\let\arrowuse=\arrowfilldraw}}
\tikzset{ctikzarrdraw/false/.code={\let\arrowuse=\arrowfillonly}}


\pgfdeclareshape{currarrow}{
    \savedanchor{\northeast}{%
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
        \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/current arrow scale}
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@circ@res@step
        \pgf@y=\pgf@x%
    }
    \anchor{north}{\northeast\pgf@x=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{east}{\northeast\pgf@y=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{south}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y \pgf@x=0cm\relax}
    \anchor{west}{\northeast\pgf@y=0cm\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
    \anchor{north west}{\northeast\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{south east}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
    \anchor{south west}{\northeast\pgf@y=-\pgf@y\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{tip}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
        \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/current arrow scale}
        \pgf@x  =\pgf@circ@res@step
    }
    \behindforegroundpath{
        \pgfscope
            \pgf@circ@res@step = \pgf@circ@Rlen
            \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/current arrow scale}

            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{-.8\pgf@circ@res@step}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{.8\pgf@circ@res@step}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.7\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
            \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
            % this is the change needed: substitute the \pgfpathuse{...} with:
            \arrowuse
        \endpgfscope
    }
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (6,2) to [american voltage source, v_=$\omega_RL_qi_q$] ++(0,-2);
    \draw[color=lightgray, densely dotted] %or dashed
    (8,2) to [american voltage source, v_=$\omega_R\psi$,color=lightgray] ++(0,-2);
    \draw[color=lightgray, densely dotted] %or dashed
    (10,2) to [american voltage source, v_=$\omega_R\psi$,color=lightgray, ctikzarrdraw=false] ++(0,-2);
    \draw[] (12,2) to [american current source, ] ++(0,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

And you'll have

[image]

Zooming:

[image]

and if you add, for example

```
\def\arrowstrange{\pgfsetfillcolor{white}\pgfusepath{fill, draw}}
\tikzset{ctikzarrdraw/strange/.code={\let\arrowuse=\arrowstrange}}
```

you can also say

```
\draw[color=lightgray, densely dotted] %or dashed
(10,2) to [american voltage source, v_=$\omega_R\psi$,color=lightgray,  ctikzarrdraw=strange] ++(0,-2);
```

which will give:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I checked. I can't change the `fill,draw` to `fill`, because the `tip` anchor will be misplaced by the line width, which is variable, which is a problem. Maybe using `\deferredanchor`...

Comment: ...and no, doesn't work.

Comment: Your last answer with the unfilled arrowhead it's what I've been looking for. Unfortunately I have to use `circuitikzgit` and add some additional code before the preamble because currently I don't know, if the rest of my code is still functionally.

Comment: You can't use the released `circuitikz` because  `circuitikz/current arrow scale` is a new thing. But you can extract the definition of `currarrow` from your installation (file `pgfcircshape.tex`) and modify that...

Comment: @Rmano May I know how to remove the arrow of an american voltage source then bridge the gap it left between the text and the source drawing?

Comment: @Diaa I am not sure I understand... Could you please ask a proper question with some sketching? Then you can ping me in the comments (although I normally check all questions tagged ciruitikz).

Comment: @Rmano Kindly, find [my recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514634/2288).

Answer (score 4):

If you would rather not get into the circuitikz source, you can manually add a label.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newlength{\offset}
\makeatletter
  \let\Rlen=\pgf@circ@Rlen
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
   (8,2) to [american voltage source, v_<=$\omega_RL_qi_q$] (8,4);

\draw[lightgray,dotted] %or dashed
  (8,0) to [american voltage source,color=lightgray,name=V2] (8,2);
  \offset=\ctikzvalof{voltage/distance from line}\Rlen
  \draw[-Triangle,dotted,color=lightgray] ($(V2.se)+(\offset,0)$) --
    ($(V2.sw)+(\offset,0)$)
    node[midway,right=\offset,inner sep=2pt,color=lightgray] {$\omega_R\psi$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably cleaner, +1; but the OP seems to want a _dotted_ arrow tip, which is quite a difficult thing to make looking nice...