# CircuiTikZ: Understanding the different drawing options of the american voltage source

Tags: circuitikz

For the following,

1- why do only `american` and `american voltages` options affect the output, while `american voltage sources` doesn't?,

2- how can I make `v(t)` move down and be placed in the removed arrow position in the 2nd and 3rd cases?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V=$v(t)$,invert,a=default] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-2.5) to[american,V=$v(t)$,invert,a=american] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-5) to[american voltages ,V=$v(t)$,invert,a=american voltages] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-7.5) to[american voltage source, V=$v(t)$,invert,a=american voltage source] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `american voltage source` is a component not a voltage style.
   So, in the last case, you have two component specification `american voltage source` (american voltage source) and `V` (european voltage source). I think its taking the second specification for drawing.
   Use `to[american voltage source, v=$v(t)$]` so that the component is `american voltage source`, voltage is `$v(t)$` which will drawn in default style (european). See the fourth case in the code and output provided.
2. One way to shift the voltage label `v(t)` down is to set `bipole voltage style={yshift=-5pt}` (See the third case in figure and code). Alternatively you can try the `voltage shift=-0.5` option also (See the second case in figure and code).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V=$v(t)$,invert,a=default] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-2.5) to[american,V=$v(t)$,invert,a=american] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-5) to[voltage shift=-0.5,bipole voltage style={yshift=-5pt},american voltages ,V=$v(t)$,invert,a=american voltages] ++(2,0);
        \draw (0,-7.5) to[american voltage source,v=$v(t)$,invert,a=american voltage source] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For different line widths, is it possible to automate the placement of `v(t)` without having to guess (i.e. `-5pt`)?

Comment: @Diaa you can try the `voltage shift=-0.5` option. See if that can do the job.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code,  and `voltage shift=-0.5` works fine for most of the reasonable font widths. However, for very thick line widths, `v(t)` overlaps with the thick line as shown [here](https://i.ibb.co/0VJZbMT/image.png), which made me think that it would be cumbersome to make the gap constant and independent of the line width.